# ¿Como hacer un panel de control que pueda editar y ver los archivos subidos a partir de un formulario con HTML y PHP?

Tags: php, html, formularios

tengo un formulario hecho con html donde estan las opciones de iniciar sesion, registrarse y subir un archivo.

```
 <html>
<head>
</head>
  <body>
<h1>Registrarse</h1>
<form action="registrar.php" method="post">
 <label for="name">Nombre:</label>
<input type="text" id="name" name="name" required><br><br>
<label for="email">Correo electronico:</label>
<input type="email" id="email" name="email" required><br><br>
<label for="password">Contrasena:</label>
<input type="password" id="password" name="password" required> 
<br><br>
<input type="submit" value="Registrarse">
</form>
<h1>Iniciar sesion</h1>
<form action="sesion.php" method="post">
<label for="email">Correo electronico:</label>
<input type="email" id="email" name="email" required><br><br>
<label for="password">Contrasena:</label>
<input type="password" id="password" name="password" required> 
<br><br>
<input type="submit" value="Iniciar sesión">
</form>
<h1>Sube un Archivo</h1>
<form action="archivo.php" method="post" enctype="multipart/form- 
data">
<label for="file">Selecciona un archivo:</label>
 <input type="file" id="file" name="file" required><br><br>
 <input type="submit" value="Subir archivo">
 </form>
 </body>
 </html>
```

Tambien tengo el  codigo php  que permite que se guarden los datos en un archivo de texto como los archivos que se quiera subir en tres php diferentes para cada formulario

```
    Registrar.php
  <?php

  $name = $_POST['name'];
  $email = $_POST['email'];
  $password = $_POST['password'];


  if (empty($name) || empty($email) || empty($password)) {
  die("Todos los campos son obligatorios");
   }

    if (!filter_var($email, FILTER_VALIDATE_EMAIL)) {
   die("El correo electrónico no es válido");
       }

      $username = explode("@", $email)[0];

     $password = password_hash($password, PASSWORD_DEFAULT);

    $folder = "users/$username";
    if (!is_dir($folder)) {
      mkdir($folder);
    }

   $file = "$folder/user.txt";
    $data = "$name\n$email\n$password\n";
    file_put_contents($file, $data);

    header("Location: index.html");
    ?>

    sesion.php
   
     <?php

      session_start();

      $email = $_POST['email'];
     $password = $_POST['password'];

      if (empty($email) || empty($password)) {
      die("Todos los campos son obligatorios");
      }

      if (!filter_var($email, FILTER_VALIDATE_EMAIL)) {
      die("El correo electrónico no es válido");
      }
     $username = explode("@", $email)[0];

     $file = "users/$username/user.txt";
      if (!file_exists($file)) {
     die("El usuario no existe");
        }

     $data = file_get_contents($file);
     list($name, $email, $hash) = explode("\n", $data);

     if (!password_verify($password, $hash)) {
      die("La contraseña es incorrecta");
      }

      $_SESSION['name'] = $name;
      $_SESSION['email'] = $email;
      $_SESSION['username'] = $username;

       header("Location: panel.php");
       ?>
    archivo.php
    <?php

     session_start();


      if (!isset($_SESSION['username'])) {
      die("Debes iniciar sesión para subir un archivo");
        }
      $username = $_SESSION['username'];

      $file = $_FILES['file'];

      if ($file['error'] != 0) {
      die("Hubo un error al subir el archivo");
       }

       if ($file['size'] > 2 * 1024 * 1024) {
      die("El archivo es demasiado grande (máximo 2 MB)");
       }
        $extension = pathinfo($file['name'], 
      PATHINFO_EXTENSION);
      $name = uniqid() . ".$extension";

      $folder = "users/$username";
      $destination = "$folder/$name";
       move_uploaded_file($file['tmp_name'], $destination);

      header("Location: panel.php");
      ?>
```

Lo que busco ahora es que al iniciar sesión o al subir un archivo te lleve a un panel de usuario donde se vean los archivos subidos, y este la opción de agregar o borrar esos archivos.
lo único que tengo de código para el panel es esto no se termina viendo bien y me falta el código para que se muestren los archivos y se puedan editar

```
    panel.php
    <!DOCTYPE html>
    <html lang="es">
       <head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
      <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, 
    initial-scale=1.0">
    <title>Panel de Control</title>
    </head>
     <body>
        <h1>Bienvenido, <?php echo $_SESSION['username']; ?> 
       </h1>

        <a href="cerrar_sesion.php">Cerrar sesión</a>
       </body>
        </html>
```

También tengo el código para cerrar sesión, pero con ese no hay problema.
Espero me puedan ayudar.

Comment: Difícil, muy difícil ayudarte. Porque no mejor buscas algún panel ya creado y analizas como se hace y/o lo adaptas a tu gusto??

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Primero que nada...
Estaria bien que nos evitaras leer todo tu codigo en futuras ocasiones cuando quieres ayuda en una cosa tan concreta.

Si no he entendido mal... Buscas que en tu "panel.php" se vean los archivos del usuario conectado.

Vamos a aclarar una cosa, yo no soy diseñador xD

Vamos a proceder a que tu PHP se vea asi:

```php
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="es">
    <head>
        <meta charset="UTF-8" />
        <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0" />
        <title>Panel de Control</title>
    </head>
    <body>
        <h1>Bienvenido, <?php echo $_SESSION['username']; ?></h1>
        <a href="cerrar_sesion.php">Cerrar sesión</a>

        <section id="ficheros">
            <h2>Tus ficheros</h2>
            <?php
                /*
                 * Estas son tus variables que me las he copiado para consultar rapido
                 * $folder = "users/$username";
                 * $destination = "$folder/$name";
                 * */
                 foreach (scandir("users/{$_SESSION["username"]}") as $file) {
                     $exclude = [".", ".."]; // Añade aqui cualquier cosa que este en este directorio que no se deba mostrar en tu pagina
                     if (!in_array($file, $exclude)) {
                         echo "<article>";
                         echo "<a href='$file' download>$file</a>"; // Simplemente para que veas el fichero y lo puedas descargar
                         echo "<a href='edit.php?file=$file'>Editar</a>";
                         echo "<a href='delete.php?file=$file'>Eliminar</a>";
                         echo "</article>";
                     }
                 }
            ?>
        </section>

        <section id="upload">
            <h2>Subir fichero</h2>
            <!-- Una copia de tu formulario para subir un fichero -->
            <form action="archivo.php" method="post" enctype="multipart/form-data">
                <label for="file">Selecciona un archivo:</label>
                <input type="file" id="file" name="file" required><br><br>
                <input type="submit" value="Subir archivo">
            </form>
        </section>
    </body>
</html>
```

A continuacion haremos un protoripo de web que te deje editar el fichero
"edit.php"

```
<?php
if (!isset($_GET["file"]) throw new Exception("Fichero no recibido por GET.");
$file = $_GET["file"];
?>

<html>
    <head>
        <meta charset="UTF-8" />
        <title>Editando <?=$file?></title>
    </head>
    <body>
        <form action="save.php?file=<?=$file?>">
            <textarea name="fileContent">
                <?=file_get_contents($file)?>
            </textarea>
            <input type="submit" value="Guardar" />
        </form>
    </body>
</html>
```

Seguido de un mini scrip de guardado
"save.php"

```php
<?php
if (!isset($_GET["file"]) throw new Exception("Fichero no recibido por GET.");
$file = $_GET["file"];

(file_put_contents($file, $_GET["fileContent"]) === false) ? throw new Exception("Fallo al guardar el fichero") : header("Location: panel.php");
?>
```

Y ahora vamos a hacer un prototipo de script que elimine el susodicho fichero
"delete.php"

```php
<?php
if (!isset($_GET["file"]) throw new Exception("Fichero no recibido por GET.");
$file = $_GET["file"];
(unlink($file)) ? header("Location: panel.php") : throw new Exception("No se ha podido borrar el fichero");
?>
```

Yo solo he probado a hacer el listado de los contenidos de un directorio para poner archivos disponibles para descargar desde donde sea, el resto lo he curioseado un poco resolviendo tu pregunta.

Y en principio con esto ya tienes un punto de partida para curiosear, puedo tener errores pero al menos valorame que me he dignado a leerme toooodo tu post y he mirado como hacer el resto que pedias :)